# Daemon app with access to single user's office 365 calendar

Tags: office365api

I have a cron script that should read a specific user's Office 365 (for business) calendar. The script runs on a Unix server. For now it's perl and it uses the v1 Office 365 API, but python or node.js are also viable options.

I am also not an admin for this office/AD tenant. Allowing the script to read the calendars of all users is not possible.

I am able to read a calendar using OAuth2 if I do some user interaction, but not if I try to use a 'daemon'.

Is it possible to have a user 'allow' a daemon app to access its calendar forever?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following link:

[Building Daemon or Service Apps with Office 365 Mail, Calendar, and Contacts APIs (OAuth2 client credential flow)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/)